# Where can I go to make enhancement/feature requests for OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, accessibility, bug

Don't get me wrong, I like Lion, though I do miss many things from Snow Leopard and wish to express this to the OSX team via some sort of suggestion forum.

I'm visually impaired and the OS is seemingly becoming more and more visual.

One thing that seems to be missing which I can barely live without is the CTRL+WHEEL to zoom in/out, the options seem to be there but don't work, or somehow work differently than they used to?

Comment: The ctrl+two finger drag is working on my trackpad

Comment: I just figured out how to break the zoom thing, put your mac to sleep, fails every time, need to restart after to fix it. I have my mac go to sleep after 1 hour.

Comment: try resetting the SMC, check the console for errors on sleep/wakeup

Comment: That did the trick Agos, thanks very much. I never knew how to do this, for others it's http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964, also PRAM/NVRAM resetting could be necessary: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379

Comment: Turns out this must be a bug in Lion, it keeps cropping its ugly head in a couple of my macs.

Comment: I think you're right, I've seen it breaking many times too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the official Feedback form for OS X.

http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

The general feedback pages do get to the marketing and engineering people as well as measuring user satisfaction, but you also can sign up for a free developer account and file bugs more directly with the engineering team. It's best to reserve this for real bugs, but it's also appropriate to make usability / functional requests there too.

http://bugreporter.apple.com

Your issue where you can repeatably break a known function is clearly a bug and might get resolved much faster through the bug channel. You can upload specifics of your hardware and steps to reproduce and honest bugs get resolved quite efficiently through this channel.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you ever so much, exactly what I was after :)

Answer (score 5):

The *official* official place is http://bugreport.apple.com/. It's where developers can file bug reports/feature requests/enhancements, etc. You do need to sign up for a [free developer account](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/) to be able to submit bugs, though you don't necessarily need to know how to develop apps for OS X.

When you submit a bug through the feedback form, it's possible that someone at Apple will manually create a corresponding bug in the bug reporter system, but there's no guarantee.

Bugs submitted through the bug reporter (often referred to by its code name `Radar`) all have an official number and status (open or closed) that you can track.

Compared to the feedback form, the bug reporter can potentially offer more in the way of feedback from Apple about the bug's status: Open, Insufficient Information, Duplicate, 3rd Party to Resolve, Behaves Correctly, and Closed.

Comment: Fantastic NSGod, I would like to mark both yours and David's answers as answered for me they are both very useful. I do have a Paid developer license from my employer as I need to write iOS apps for them.

Comment: I edited @david's answer to include the bug reporter since it's selected and most voted. I felt it important to get that in the main reply and discuss the difference between general feedback and a bug. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

- E-mail Steve Jobs directly for feature requests
- Look at this question for [enabling Screen Zoom in lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18857/is-screen-zoom-broken-in-lion)

Comment: You can email Steve directly? I'm sure he wouldn't want to hear from some almost blind guy! I've pretty much got all that done on that question, clicking "ON" turns zoom on permanently in a fixed position that the mouse doesn't want to allow the screen to move, I'll try post on youtube.

Comment: Ah bugger, QuickTime doesn't capture the zooming behaviour, however this upload to YouTube shows that I've got the right settings ticked. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MauK5nRHQg&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: It seems after I turned on/off the features and restarted it fixed the problem, thanks macaco.

Comment: Is emailing Steve really the only way to get enhancement requests/suggestions?

Comment: Brett, it kinda said it with tongue in cheek, but Steve does respond to some e-mails (usually in a very terse manner). Check out the feedback form posted below by David :)

Comment: No, no, no - a thousand times no. Don't even joke about that. For every "famous reply" can you imagine how little weight your "feedback" will have if someone checks and sees you haven't let the normal process have a chance at handling your bug/feedback. You don't honestly think he reads his mail before several people have filtered the vast majority of mails sent to "steve", do you? He might check his unfiltered stream at precisely the moment you mailed, but why risk it.

Answer (score 0):

Me too I use a lot the screen zooming and I'm quite annoyed by this small bug.

In addition to the solutions already provided, I've found out that playing a bit with "System preferences" -> "Universal Access" solves the problem (until it appears next time).

From this screen, after playing a bit with the options about Zooming and testing with ctrl-2fingers, I get the feature back, then it doesn't really matter if I set the zoom on or of: it keeps working.

This behavior is quite odd indeed, but at least I don't have to restart services or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is also the [OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/page/1) project to bring these reports out into the open, but it could use a lot of work.